# macOS Monterey DNS lookups fail after a few hours

Tags: macos, network, dns, monterey

I upgraded my M1 Mac to macOS Monterey recently and it seems that there are DNS lookup issues that eventually stop me from using the internet. Restarting the computer fixes the problem but eventually the DNS problems start cropping up again.

I have no idea what is causing this issue... it's frustrating to constantly have to restart my laptop every so often just to get internet access.

My iPhone is able to use the internet just fine whenever these DNS issues occur. I would appreciate any guidance that can be given to help me resolve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I finally figured it out after some research.

Previously I had Cisco AnyConnect installed and [apparently that causes issues on macOS Monterey.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253295978)

I just had my internet stop working, so I uninstalled AnyConnect – and my browsers magically became able to connect to websites again :)